# Why does GCC put a no-op push/pop when using int foo asm("ebx") to pin a var to a register?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I'm trying to write code to read from a register, and this is what I have so far:

```
unsigned int readEBX(void) {
    register unsigned int reg asm("ebx");
    return reg;
}
```

The function appears to be working, but it compiles to something strange:

```
readEBX():
    mov  eax, ebx
    push ebx
    pop  ebx
    ret
```

Why should this push-then-pop ebx? Doesn't this do nothing? When I replace `ebx` for another register (say `eax` or `ecx`), then it produces saner code (just a `ret` and a `mov eax, ecx; ret` respectively).

See this example [Godbolt result](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22K4Owzglg5iCmAmACCIAuiBOsCG8CiAQgBoAUAbgPYTwCUiA3gFCKaxQRiqwaKiQwJkaVlETYwAWxIAiWACMAHtJoBuZq1TAMIEWoC%2BQA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g520%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O3%20-m32%22%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: `esi`, `edi`, and `ebp` as well.

Comment: It's a bug. Report it.

Comment: Those three are the callee-save registers, but there doesn't seem to be any reason to do the push/pop

Comment: I suspect returning an uninitialized value is undefined behavior, but I'll have to check...

Comment: This could be a hint about why GCC treats these 4 registers differently: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html

Comment: @user3629249 That is not what `ret` does: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html

Comment: GCC bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67944

Comment: @AlexReinking, you may notice, after re-reading the question, I deleted my comment.

Comment: It's not a bug. The code doesn't initialize `reg` so GCC can return any value. The `asm("ebx")` just tells GCC to use EBX for `reg`, it doesn't say `reg` should have any particular value. In particular it doesn't say that it should have the value previously stored in EBX.

Comment: Also, the standard explicitly forbids to read uninitialized `register` variables, even variables that "could" be declared as `register`, i.e where the address is never taken. The behavior of your program is not defined.

Comment: @JensGustedt you may very well be right, although then the gcc docs are misleading. What does the standard say about gcc extensions (like explicit register vars)?

Comment: @AlexReinking, this is the whole sense of the notion of undefined. The standard doesn't foresee any behavior for such cases, simply to allow compiler implementors to chose whatever they need. Also the notion of `register` in the standard has not much to do with hardware registers. They are just adressless objects.

Comment: @JensGustedt since it's about a extension not governed by the C standard, why is it even part of the discussion? And even though the compiler was allowed to generate that code, that doesn't mean it's not a bug to *actually* do it

Comment: @harold, the `asm` is an extension, but I am not aware that gcc says something about non-initialized `register` objects. The two are not related. If gcc doesn't define precisely what has to happen if you use a hardware register without initializing it, anything can happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are explicitly telling the compiler that you are interested in the register, he tries to be smart. Since you want to observe the register, don't tell the compiler, so he can't mess around.

This works for me (modulo the order of the `mov` operation)

```
unsigned int readEBX(void) {
  register unsigned int ret __asm__("eax");
  __asm__ volatile("mov %%ebx, %0" : "=r"(ret));
  return ret;
}
```

It just ensures that `ret` uses a different register, so there is no conflict.

Comment: This does, indeed, work for me, so +1. But then so did the other approach, correctness-wise. It's just suboptimal. This doesn't really explain why the bug exists since ret doesn't clobber a register. It's basically just a `pop eip`

Comment: You probably don't need the `volatile` on that asm statement unless `ebx` is being changed asynchronously.  i.e. use `volatile` if you want to stop gcc from hoisting `readEBX` out of a loop, or re-ordering memory operations around it.  Avoid `volatile` if that kind of optimization is desirable.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I think for such a "function" you don't want it to be reordered under any circumstance. This is inspecting the runtime environment, so you want to place it exactly where the programmer wants it.

Comment: @AlexReinking, I don't think that this is a bug. You are reading an uninitialized `register` variable, this is explicitly forbidden by the standard. So your program has no defined behavior.

Comment: Using `asm("eax")` for the return value is completely unnecessary, and if anything might lead to worse code when inlining.  (It might still force the use of `eax` after inlining).

Comment: Also, yes it is a minor missed optimization bug.  Of course it's undefined what you'll get from reading `%ebx`, but that gives the compiler more room to optimize, not less.  The only way I can see this making any sense is in 32bit PIC code, where `%ebx` gets used to hold a pointer to the GOT, and doesn't change inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

Declaring a variable with a specific register is a not-widely-used feature, so reading it without ever writing it is a corner case of a corner case.

Probably declaring a variable pinned to a callee-saved register flags that register as used by the function, leading gcc to emit push/pop insns to save/restore it.

This is sub-optimal asm, but calling a function just to read ebx is a lot of wasted overhead, too.  This function should be fine when inlined, unless it's being inlined into a function that also doen't use ebx itself.  In that case, you should make `readEBX` a macro that uses the inline asm from Jens' answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know the function interface isn't great, but thanks to the existing codebase, there are situations in which a function pointer to this function will need to be passed, so a macro won't suffice. =/

Comment: @Alex: Don't worry too much about the push/pop in the stand-alone version, if the `int reg asm("ebx")` version leads to better code when the function is inlined than the inline asm version. All 4 of the insns can issue in the same cycle, and they're not wasting uop-cache space because unconditional jumps (like `ret`) end a uop cache-line anyway. It should only slow you down if load-port or store-port uops are the bottleneck in your code (highly unlikely).  Or slow you down by one cycle on Atom, if uop tput is the bottleneck. Just make sure it inlines well. (or re-design your nasty code!)

Comment: very good point! And believe me, I would *love* to redesign this code. Tip of the iceberg, though...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the actual origin of the odd `push/pop` sequence directly from the [above-linked](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67944) bug report<sup>1</sup>:

> Your expectation [that returning `reg` in C will return the value of `ebx` since you associated `ebx` and `reg` in the asm block] is not in line with what the
>   compiler actually promises you: the only guarantee is that the local
>   register variable will be in (in your case) ebx *where used in an asm
>   statement*.
>
> Other than that, it is just a local variable.
>
> You get a save/restore sequence in the prologue and epilogue because
>   ebx is a non-volatile register and this function uses that register. 
>   Scheduling later moves the push later in the code.
>
> If you want to simply grab what is in ebx, you can use asm, like
>
> `long reg; asm("mov %%ebx,%0" : "=r"(reg));`

So basically the `push/pop` is just there because it's a callee-saved reg, and then a later optimizer pass moves the `push` below the asm so it doesn't look exactly like a prologue anymore.

---

<sup>1</sup>Context in square brackets is mine.

Comment: You could probably just do it this way too `long reg; __asm__ __volatile__ ("" : "=b"(reg));` If I was always interested in just the 32-bit EBX register then I'd probably change _long_ to _uint32_t_ . Doing it this way also has the advantage that it works with 32-bit and 64-bit code gen.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Using `"=b"` as an output operand will get the compiler to avoid using it for whatever long-term value it normally would (e.g. GOT base), similar to declaring `uint32_t foo asm("ebx")`.  If you really wanted to see what the compiler was keeping in EBX without disturbing it, probably use something dumb like `asm volatile("mov %ebx, %0" : "=g"(copy_of_ebx))`.  Oh, that's what this already suggests.  Or use a debugger like a normal person!